# What am i doing wrong in writing this Snowflake function with variables?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-function

Another user was helping me with this problem, but i'm having trouble executing it, i'm getting error:

`syntax error line 3 at position 8 unexpected 'time'. syntax error line 3 at position 23 unexpected ':'. (line 3)`

it seems i'm either declaring the variables wrong, actually i'm sure of that because when i comment out "time", it gives me an error with "curDay".

Here is the function i'm trying to execute;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_AAR.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime (dateTime TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), shiftCalendarID int)

RETURNS table (shiftID int)
AS
$$
DECLARE
        time time TIME(:dateTime);
        curDay  int;
        prvDay  int;
        shiftID int;
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID,
        DATEDIFF( day, BeginDate, :dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1,
        ( :curDay + PeriodInDays - 2 ) % PeriodInDays + 1
        INTO :shiftCalendarID, :curDay, :prvDay
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = :shiftCalendarID
        OR (    :shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= :dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC;

SELECT ID into :shiftID
    FROM Shift
    WHERE ShiftCalendarID = @shiftCalendarID
        AND (  ( FromDay = :curDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= :time         AND TillTimeOfDay >  :time )
            OR ( FromDay = :curDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= :time )
            OR ( FromDay = :prvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  :time )
        );
    END;
$$
```

Comment: There is no declare section in a SQL UDTF, and it must have a single SQL statement. This definition has two. A SQL UDTF also does not use a begin or end keyword. This syntax is relevant to SQL Stored Procedures. Perhaps your use case could use a stored procedure instead?

Comment: If you do require a function, consider combining the 2 SQL statements into a single CTE.

Comment: the reason i have it as a function is because it gets called in a where clause for a view i'm writing. i cant make it a stored procedure because i cant call a stored procedure in a where clause. what i have written above is a function pulled from a sql server. 

how would you write this?

Comment: @DaveWelden how do i define a variable in a cte, meaning how do i call it? any links to an example?

Comment: A simple example of defining a variable (in this case variable is descendant): 

-- Ancestors query
WITH q(descendant) AS
(
  SELECT 'S02300'
)
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.ccname,
    a.hierarchy
FROM costcenter a
JOIN costcenter d
JOIN q
ON ARRAY_INTERSECTION(a.hierarchy,d.hierarchy) = a.hierarchy
WHERE d.id = q.descendant
ORDER BY hierarchy;

Answer (score 2):

To add on to [Dave Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74225895/20275694)'s solution - in UDF bodies, there are no colons in front of parameters. Instead of `:shiftCalendarID` it is `shiftCalendarID` and `:dateTime` is just `dateTime`. Colons are needed in Stored Procedures, because the parameters are treated as string literal constants, but this is not the case with User Defined Functions.

Answer (score 1):

This may need some small changes, but should be close to what you require:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_AAR.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime (dateTime TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), shiftCalendarID int)

RETURNS table (shiftID int)
AS
$$
WITH T0 (ShiftCalendarID, CurDay, PrvDay)
AS (
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID AS ShiftCalendarID,
        DATEDIFF( day, BeginDate, :dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS CurDay,
        ( CurDay + PeriodInDays - 2 ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS PrvDay
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = :shiftCalendarID
        OR (    :shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= :dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC
),
T1 (TimeValue)
AS (
    SELECT TIME_FROM_PARTS(
        EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM :datetime),
        EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM :datetime),
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM :datetime))
    )
)
SELECT ID as shiftID
    FROM Shift, T0, T1
    WHERE Shift.ShiftCalendarID = T0.ShiftCalendarID
    AND (  ( FromDay = T0.CurDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= T1.TimeValue AND TillTimeOfDay >  T1.TimeValue )
            OR ( FromDay = T0.CurDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= T1.TimeValue )
            OR ( FromDay = T0.PrvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  T1.TimeValue )
        );
$$
```

Comment: this looks exactly like what i'd need, it seems like there's an extra ) which i removed and the semicolon which snowflake does not like. but i'm getting this error. 

`syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected 'WITH'.
syntax error line 2 at position 9 unexpected 'ShiftCalendarID'.
syntax error line 6 at position 65 unexpected 'AS'. (line 2)`

Comment: so the issue was the extra "WITH T1", i totally missed that since it's a CTE it doesn't need it again. however, now i got a bind error. `Bind variables not allowed in view and UDF definitions.`

Comment: SQL scripting is very limited in Snowflake. You may need to rewrite this as a Java, JavaScript, or Python UDTF in order to work around those limitations.

Comment: darn. those are languages i dont know.... i'll look into it.

Comment: In my opinion, you should either consider JavaScript or Python. JavaScript was the original Snowflake language and seems to be the primary one supported. Python is my personal favorite. It is not too difficult to learn and is one of the top programming languages for many use cases beyond Snowflake.